# Facebook Graph API in aws lambda failing

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm having trouble getting this to run. It runs just fine if I make the same FB.api call directly from the front end or through "serverless invoke local" and it console.logs my response. But when I deploy this function to a lambda and try to call it, I hit the "console.log("TRY"), get a 502 error, and then nothing after that. No response from the FB.api call, no errors, no info at all. I've tried upping the timeout as well and have brought it up to as much as 15 seconds and still getting no response. Anyone else run into this? Thanks!

```html
export async function main(event, context, callback){
    var FB = require('fb');
    const data = JSON.parse(event.body)
    console.log("DATA: ", data)
    const requestString = data.Id + '/accounts'
    console.log(requestString)
    console.log("ACCESS TOKEN: ", data.accessToken)
    const pages = []
    try{
    console.log("TRY")
       await FB.api(requestString, 'get', { access_token: data.accessToken }, function(response){
            console.log("RESPONSE: ", response)
            callback(null, success(response));
       })
    }
    catch (e){
        console.log("CATCH")
        console.log(e)
        callback(null, failure({ status: false }));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: _“I hit the "console.log("TRY"), get a 502 error”_ - where from - your own script, or as response from the API?

Comment: The 502 is a response from the lambda, not from the FB api. I don't get a response from the FB.api call where typically it'll return an error in the response from facebook. but instead it just never runs.

Comment: Which version of Node are you using ? (the one declared in your serverless.yml as `provider: runtime:`)